# regular match zero or one

Tags: regex

- target string

  - "hello/123 timo build/123"  string A
  - "hello/234 mimo world" string B
- what do I want?

  - get `hello number`
  - get `build number` if exist
- I tried four expressions, but all not work

```golang
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "regexp"
    )

    var a = "hello/123 timo build/123"
    var b = "hello/234 mimo world"

    func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
        r1 := regexp.MustCompile(`(hello/[\d]+).*(build/[\d]+)`)
            r2 := regexp.MustCompile(`(hello/[\d]+).*?(build/[\d]+)`)
            r3 := regexp.MustCompile(`(hello/[\d]+).*(build/[\d]+)?`)
            r4 := regexp.MustCompile(`(hello/[\d]+).*?(build/[\d]+)?`)

            fmt.Println(r1.FindStringSubmatch(a))
            fmt.Println(r2.FindStringSubmatch(a))
            fmt.Println(r3.FindStringSubmatch(a))
            fmt.Println(r4.FindStringSubmatch(a))

            fmt.Println(r1.FindStringSubmatch(b))
            fmt.Println(r2.FindStringSubmatch(b))
            fmt.Println(r3.FindStringSubmatch(b))
            fmt.Println(r4.FindStringSubmatch(b))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this :
[`^hello\/(\d+).+?(?:build\/(\d+))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/HvrqVY/3)

First group of numbers corresponds to "hello" and second to "build". Once you extract numbers - append required words to them.

Comment: thanks, it seems `^(hello/[\d]+).*?(build/[\d]+)?$`(with `^` and `$`) works as expect, but `(hello/[\d]+).*?(build/[\d]+)?` doesn't. But I don't know why...

Comment: That's because `.*?` is a _non-greedy_ match, and due to fact you remove start and end tags in expression regex is not forced to scan up to the end of string, so non-greedy match succeeds taking at least 1 additional character after first group. If you want similar effect without using ^ and $ (albeit they are pretty standard), you can try this regex which tries to match exact pattern between your capture groups `hello\/(\d+)\s\w+\s(?:build\/(\d+))?`. But again this is not also ideal. If number of spaces in a middle of string changes, or something else - this will fail too. Constant fight :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar with your expressions and I could not make them work.

But the following seems to do the job:

```
(((hello)[\/\s]*(\d*).*?(build)[\/\s]*(\d*).*$)|((hello)[\/\s]*(\d*).*?$))
```

Now you only need to get the results form the proper capture groups.

The trick is that I actually created separate expressions for each case, when "build" exists, and for when it does not.

Try [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/xzNadl/1).

Comment: Thanks,  it seems `^(hello/[\d]+).*?(build/[\d]+)?$`(with ^ and $) works as expect.